# Any two closed curves in $S^2$ has intersection $0$ mod $2$.

Tags: differential-topology, intersection-theory

I know that $S^2$ is simply connected since by Sard's theorem any curve in $S^2$ ($1$ dimensional manifold) is a measure zero set hence it should be contained in $S^2-\{p\} $ for some $p\in S^2$ and $S^2-\{p\}\cong \Bbb{R}^2$ is simply connected.

But from this I cannot prove any two curves in $S^2$ has intersection $0$ mod $2$. Can anyone help me to complete the proof?

Comment: How do u define the intersection no?

Comment: You probably need some stronger restrictions on those two curves. In particular, you might want to exclude tangential intersections.

Comment: If you want to argue geometrically, you can use the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: Sard's theorem says any curve has measure zero? Weierstrass will be interested...

Comment: @Thorgott I don't see how JCT applies - we need to show that _any_ (possibly not simple) closed curve is null-homotopic

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I meant to argue geometrically that the mod 2 intersection number is zero, not that the sphere is simply connected. In that context, "curve" should mean "smooth submanifold diffeomorphic to $S^1$", so JCT applies.

Comment: You started right, but you want more than simple connectivity. The point is that $S^2-\{p\} \cong \Bbb R^2$ is *contractible*. Now compute intersection numbers.